# Serverless on gcp add custom http path

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, serverless

I have this serverless function that I deploy on Google Cloud Functions but I want it to sit at a custom http path instead of the function handler name.

```
functions:
  board_meta:
    memorySize: 128
    handler: boardMeta
    events:
      - http: board-meta
```

The desired path is `board-meta` but this simply ignores the `- http: board-meta` direction. And it deploys the function with `boardMeta` as a path.

I also tried with:

```
functions:
  board_meta:
    memorySize: 128
    handler: boardMeta
    events:
      - http: 
        path: board-meta
```

This results with an error:

```
Deployment failed: CONDITION_NOT_MET

     "/httpsTrigger/url": domain: validation; keyword: type; message: instance does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: ["string"]; found: "null"
```